# Acts as follower installaion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to use [acts_as_follower](https://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_follower) to work but I am surely doing something wrong in the routes.

Added the gem:

`gem 'acts_as_follower`

In the User model:

`acts_as_follower`

`acts_as_followable`

In the Post model:

`acts_as_followable`

In my page controller:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def profile
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc").where( "user_id = ?", User.find_by_id(params[:id]) )
    @post = Post.new  
  end

  def feed
    @posts = Post.all.order("RANDOM()")
  end

  def home

  end

  def follow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def unfollow
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end

  def block
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @post.block(@user)
  end
end
```

In my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts

  devise_for :users
  root 'page#index'
  get '/users/:id' => 'page#profile'
  get 'page/feed'
  get 'page/home'

  resources :users do
    get :follow
    get :unfollow
  end
end
```

The thing is, I always get an exception error with user_id set to nil even though the Users table (devise) doesn't have a user_id column?

Why is it searching for a user_id when I defined @user in my controller?

Is the issue inside the routes.rb?

**Update**

Full Post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
    acts_as_followable
end
```

Full User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Full trace log:

```
app/views/page/profile.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_page_profile_html_erb__881455127_39547752'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Profile view:

```
<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
<%= link_to "Follow", follow_user_path(@user) %>
<br>
<br>
<%= render 'posts/form' %>

<br>
<br>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <p><%= post.description %>, <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago</p>
       <%= image_tag post.avatar, :class => "tumbnial" %>
       <br>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if post.user_id == current_user.id %>
                <%= link_to "Delete post", post_path(post), :method => :delete %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see your models and full exception log.

Comment: @BorisPilgun, updated the question

Comment: Ok, please add also content of app/views/page/profile.html.erb and rendered within it partials if any. - as you can see from logs error starting there.  Also if you can include full error with error message and error description if it present instead just stack trace. Don't hesitate to add as much as possible info for debugging this, it simplifies process :)

Comment: @BorisPilgun I added the profile view code but as for the error logs that is it I posted them all. The error basically starts with `<%= link_to "follow", follow_user_path(@user)` I am getting the user id as nil which is why the error is happening in the first place. But I don't why I am getting it since I did define the user instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Raymond looks like you missed initialization of `@user` instance in your `profile` action:

```
  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: @user.id)
    @post = Post.new  
  end
```

Also note that when you use `find_by_id(...)` to find user you'll get nil, if user will not be found, so might be incorrect behavior in next code. Better to use `find(...)` which will raise an exception and you can handle it somehow, for example by redirecting to some page with flash message about it or you can do the same using `find_by_id` but make sure user was found.

And probably better extract this functionality to some before_action, e.g.:

```
class PageController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_user, only: [:profile, :follow, :unfollow, :block]
  def profile
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at desc").where(user_id: @user.id)
    @post = Post.new  
  end

  def feed
    @posts = Post.all.order("RANDOM()")
  end

  def home; end

  def follow
    current_user.follow(@user)
  end

  def unfollow
    current_user.stop_following(@user)
  end

  def block
    @post.block(@user)
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    # here you can redirect to some place with flash message if @user.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: You are a life saver :P